# Dynamically Theme Boolean Fields

Tags: theming, entities

I am trying to dynamically display boolean fields into columns based on their value.  So for instance these 10 boolean fields on my node, if marked 1, I want it to theme it so that they show up in a column to the left titled Completed, and if marked 0, a column to the right titled Not Complete.  I have tried using template.php and field.tpl.php but I am getting very lost.

I'd like to do this on the field node being viewed (not using Views) as a custom dynamic field formatter that applies a different css class to the field div.  That or in the theme layer using some php magic.

Comment: I had a little trouble understanding your question, could edit it to clarify what you're asking?  Are you displaying a view?  Or is this just a node being displayed?

Comment: This is the display of fields on a node.  I'm trying to do this in the theme layer but I don't know where to start.  Basically I'm trying to do something similar to http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class but rather than apply a css class to the whole node and hide the field, I want to apply it to the field formatter so that I can theme boolean field outputs differently based on their value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think this might be what you're looking for:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7

I'd throw that function on your template.php, enable the Devel module, then use kpr() to print the variables to the screen and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easier than I thought.  Here is some example code.  Just change template in template_preprocess_field to the name of your theme and put it in template.php with an opening php tag.

```
    /*
 * Implements template_preprocess_field()
 */
function template_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  //check to see if the field is a boolean
  if ($vars['element']['#field_type'] == 'list_boolean') {
    //check to see if the value is TRUE
    if ($vars['element']['#items'][0]['value'] == '1') {
      //add the class .is-true
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'is-true';
    } else {
      //add the class .is-false
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'is-false';
    }
  }
}
```